# Как вернуть два значения из метода java?

Tags: java

Подскажите плиз как вернуть два значения (max, idx) из метода в java?

```
private static int findMaximum(int[] array) {
        int max = 0;
        int idx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] % 3 == 0 && max < array[i]) { //поиск максимального числа кратного 3м
                max = array[i];
                idx = i;
            }
        }
        if (max == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Максимального числа кратного 3-м не знайдено");
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: Через массив или класс.

Comment: Ну или как вариант `Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>`

Comment: ну  или по простецки вернуть  String :  String result =  firstValue +"_" + secondValue; А потом   разобрать  строку  используя ValueOf

Answer (score 4):

Создайте вспомогательный класс:

```java
public class Result {
    final int max;
    final int position;

    public Result(int max, int position) {
        this.max = max;
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

Теперь в методе `findMaximum()` возвращайте объект `Result`:

```java
private Result findMaximum(int[] array) {
    int max = 0;
    int idx = 0;
    ...
    return new Result(max, idx);
}
```

Использование:

```java
Result result = findMaximum(array);
System.out.println(result.max);
System.out.println(result.position);
```

Comment: Может использовать Класс кортежей javatuples ? Чтобы велосипед не изобретать?

Comment: @Виктор как раз лучше их не использовать, чтобы потом не разбираться, что в возвращаемом Pair лежит в left, а что в right.