# Return в виде разных данных как правильно делается?

Tags: java, return

В продолжение этой темы.
[Как создать массив хранящий переменные разных типов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709147/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2/1461707?noredirect=1#comment2613890_1461707)

Хорошо бы пример увидеть этого MethodResult, а то непонятно, как его реализовывать.
Где нужно ставить "return new MethodResult"?
Что с final делать, они все красной ошибкой горят?
Как присваивать значения всему этому классу?
Тоже хотел из функции сделать возвратный массив с разными данными (стринг, вебэлемент, стринг дополнительный).
А как правильно сделать предложенным классом, так и не понял.
Да и вообще, актуальна эта информация или нет?

(aleksandr barakin посоветовал написать именно новой темой)

Comment: что за язык-то? можно ли чуть больше примеров? а то на словах что-то на оч. всё ясно что какие проблемы

Comment: Язык Java. Функция выдает два типа данных (String, WebElement). Мне их надо вывести из функции (return). Вывести думал в виде массива (1 - String, 2 - WebElement, 3 - String). Но прочитал, что так делать не правильно, а правильно через класс. А как именно, я так и не понял.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть два значения из метода java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1454439/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-java)

Comment: Слишком много вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Создай новый класс, и определи свойства String и WebElement. Возвращаемый тип функции укажи новоиспеченный класс.

Пример:

```
public class Entity {
    private final String str1;
    private final String str2;
    private final WebElement webElem;

    // Getters & Setters or create constructor
}

public class Main {
    public Entity generateEntity() {
        Entity ent = new Entity();
        ent.setStr1("Hello");
        ent.setStr2("World");
        ent.setWebElem(new WebElement());
        return ent;
    }
}
```

Можно не через сеттеры создавать объект, а через конструктор. Надеюсь посыл понятен. Такой паттерн называется Data Transfer Object (DTO). [Здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern) хорошо описаны примеры и задумка.

Comment: 1. Если поля определены как финальные, то сеттеров для данного класса не надо. 2. Для реализации DTO можно использовать кортежи `record`